# Streetlevel example not working

Tags: javascript, here-api

I can't make work the new Streetlevel Javascript example (http://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/v3/maps/topics/panorama.html ).
I undestand the problem is "mapElement" in the constructor, but I can't figure out what is this parameter.
My app has a Base plan license.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width"/>
    <script src="http://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-core.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="http://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-service.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="http://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-pano.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
    <div style="width: 640px; height: 480px" id="basemap"></div>
    <br> <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    // Create a Platform object:
    var platform = new H.service.Platform({
        'app_id': 'my_app_id',
        'app_code': 'my_app_code'
    });

    var basemap = document.getElementById('basemap');

    var maptypes = platform.createDefaultLayers()

    // Configure panorama with platform credentials:
    platform.configure(H.map.render.panorama.RenderEngine);

    // Instantiate a map, giving the constructor the engine type to use:
    map = new mapsjs.Map(mapElement, basemap, {
        center: {lat: 48.8733641244471, lng: 2.294754032045603},
        zoom: 19,
        engineType: H.Map.EngineType.PANORAMA
    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to render the panorama:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width"/>
    <script src="http://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-core.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="http://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-service.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="http://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-pano.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="http://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-mapevents.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>  

</head>
<body>
    <div style="width: 800px; height: 600px" id="basemap"></div>
    <br> 
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            // Create a Platform object:
            var platform = new H.service.Platform({
                'app_id': 'my_app_id',
                'app_code': 'my_app_code'
            });


        // Get an object containing the default map layers:
        var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();


            // Configure panorama with platform credentials:
            platform.configure(H.map.render.panorama.RenderEngine);

                  // Instantiate the map using the normal map as the base layer:
                  var map = new H.Map(document.getElementById('basemap'), defaultLayers.normal.panorama, {
                    center: {lat: 48.8733641244471, lng: 2.294754032045603},
                    zoom: 18,
                    engineType: H.Map.EngineType.PANORAMA
                });


          // Enable the event system on the map instance:
          var mapEvents = new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map);

        // Add event listeners:
        map.addEventListener('tap', function(evt) {
            // Log 'tap' and 'mouse' events:
            console.log(evt.type, evt.currentPointer.type); 
        });        

         // Instantiate the default behavior, providing the mapEvents object: 
         var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(mapEvents);       

         </script>
</body>
</html>
```